# Tkinter changing image live after a given time

Tags: python, tkinter

I currently have a listbox with the paths of dozens of images, when an element in the listbox is selected the image will be displayed in the middle of the gui.

My third image has 2 different looks to it so i wrote:

```
        #Third image
        elif (self.index==3):
            start = clock()
            self.label.configure(image=self.photo2[1])#first image
            if (start>2):
                self.label.configure(image=self.photo2[2])#second image
```

For now when the user clicks the third element it will first display the first image, then if reclicked after two seconds it will display the second image, so that works.

However, what I want is for my third image to automatically change after two seconds without reclicking. Is there a way to update an image live in tkinter or any ideas on what approach I could take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common pattern. You should use `Tk.after` to run a function that changes the image then schedules the next change.

```
def change_image(label, imagelist, nextindex):
    label.configure(image=imagelist[nextindex])
    root.after(2000, lambda: change_image(label, imagelist, (nextindex+1) % len(imagelist)))
```

Then call it once and let it do its thing forever.

```
root = Tk()
setup_your_stuff()
change_image(root.label, root.photo2, 0)
```

Comment: There were things i needed to change but tk.after is exactly what i was looking for, thank you!